# set image from external url as featured image if its not present

Tags: php, wordpress

i m trying to set a fallback image which is already uploaded to the site/present in media library as featured image if there's no featured image when i click on publish or update but it doesn't set the image. nothing happens

**code in functions.php**

```
function thumb_check($post_id){    
$url="http://example.com/uploads/flower.png";    
if (has_post_thumbnail( $post_id)){}    
else { update_post_meta($post_id,'_thumbnail_id',$url);}    
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'thumb_check' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_thumbnail_id` only works for WP photo id not URLs. Take a look at at this post https://wordpress.org/support/topic/_thumbnail_id-not-display-when-full-url-of-image

Here is my suggestion:

**UPDATE:** `url_to_postid` doesn't seem to work very well on my end. You should go to **Media** then look for your fallback image id and manually placing the image id in the code bellow. To see the image id look at the url it should look like http://example.com/wp-admin/upload.php?item=51 where **51** is the image id. Also, I replaced `update_post_meta` with `set_post_thumbnail`

***functions.php***

```
function thumb_check($post_id) {
    if(!has_post_thumbnail($post_id)) {
        set_post_thumbnail($post_id, 51)
    }
}

add_action('save_post', 'thumb_check');
```

Comment: the post still doesn't show up the backup image in the featured image window of the post

Comment: plz note the the image is already present /uploaded to the site from before

Comment: the image e.g attachment_id=638 so i replaced 51 with 638 but nothing...from what i understand via google tht set_post_thumbnail no longer works properly

Comment: @user3117694 What version are you using? I'm using version 4.1 and it works fine on my end.

Comment: me too...i m able to retrieve the imageid correctly but for some reason i can't see it within the post

Comment: ok it works...the problem was previous it had attached it probbaly and not showing up so hasthumbnail was proving wrong and it was not setting the thumbnail...thanx!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69050/discussion-between-yoel-nunez-and-user3117694).